# jQuery ajax callback function not working

Tags: jquery, cross-browser

I am using Symfony PHP Framework to create web application, and using symfony Forms to create the HTML forms. I am trying to load the data in Select element using Ajax, for that i am using jQuery's Ajax functions. It is working fine as it sends and gets the response correctly(status as 200), but not calling the Callback function in some browsers such as IE,Chrome and Safari.It works fine in Firefox and Opera.
the Code that is not working,

```
$.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'form/ajax',
                    async: true,
                    cache: false,
                    dataType : 'json',
                    data: 'id='+ids,
                    success: function(jsonData){
                        alert("ok go");                            
                    }
         });
```

the alert "OK Go" is not called in Chrome,IE and Safari
But

```
$.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'form/ajax',
                    async: true,
                    cache: false,
                    dataType : 'json',
                    data: 'id='+ids,
                    success: alert("ok go");                            

         });
```

this works, but as per the project i want the JSON data to load in my Select element.
is there any thing wrong in the return JSON format or the bug in the jQuery Ajax functions, please help.

Comment: Something to note, in your second example "ok go" is called WHILE the `.ajax` is being configured not during it's callback. That is to say, it's taking the "result of `alert()`" and assigning that value to callback parameter, _then_ passing those values to `.ajax` for execution.

Comment: @ Brad Christie ok, but in the first example, it is not returning the data send by the server in jsonData variable?? and hence not working in other browsers other than Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all thanks @Kamyar and @Brad Christie, to help me solve the problem. while inspecting as Kamyar said to change the format of id to JSON format, i checked the return format for JSON, and found that it was causing the problem, as it was not a valid JSON format. The return JSON format was causing the Problem! 
return JSON with error,

```
{"ugdegree":[{"id":31,"specialization":"Dentistry"},{"id":32,"specialization":"Other"},]}
```

there was an extra comma at the end(causing the problem)
Now it has been fixed! 
so if anyone having the same problem, please check for the JSON format! if that might be the case.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. replace `'id=' + ids` with `'id:'+ids`

UPDATE: I've written a JQuery plugin which makes ajax calls and json serializing very easier. you can download it at: http://www.4shared.com/file/8hHJll-R/Pagemethod-2.html

Comment: and @Kamyar it was not an error caused due to the DATA which was send but the return data send from server..